# How to remove extra quotes while saving dataframe into file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have below data in dataframe

```
df
col1
my name is shi"vam
```

I am running below code:

```
df.toPandas().to_csv(ec2_key, sep='|', encoding='utf-8', header=True, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

When I am opening this file in Notepad++ it's converting data into

```
"col1"
"my name is shi""vam"
```

I want below record as output

```
"col1"
"my name is shi"vam"
```

I don't want to remove quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL.

Without removing it how can get desirable output? I know csv.QUOTE_NONE can work but I want to use csv.QUOTE_ALL and get the desirable result. It is not for just one column. If I want to do it for entire dataframe then what to do that time?

Comment: @Bhargav-RetardedSkills Thank you for your response. Here QUOTE_NONE is using but I want to use QUOTE_ALL

Comment: Below code help you

data = {'col1': ['my name is shi"vam']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace('"', '|||')

df.to_csv('output.csv', sep='|', encoding='utf-8', header=True, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

df = pd.read_csv('output.csv', sep='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace('|||', '"')

Comment: You're asking how to purposely generate invalid CSV, pandas doesn't do that. Just use thd (valid) default.